# Why is this piece of Kotlin code printing out a different value than what's in the memory

Tags: spring, kotlin

This is the snippet of the code I can't wrap my head around. It's making a request using a rest template and then prints out the value of `running` using the print statement on line 4. On the last line it saves the value of `finished` in the database.

```
val response: ResponseEntity<StatusResponse> = restTemplate.exchange(...
val jobTaskStatus = response.body.state
if (response.statusCodeValue == 200 || response.statusCodeValue == 202)
    System.out.print("ResponsePlanStatus : " + response.body)
updateExecutionStatus(planJobID, jobTaskStatus
```

I review the log to see what was printed out and I see `running`, I go in the database to check and I see `finished` with no other log messages printing out that it was finished.

```
Mon, Nov 30, 2020 09:28:49.668
[APP/PROC/WEB/0]
OUT ResponsePlanStatus : StatusResponse(name=3351, state=running, type=task
```

So I try again but this time I connect a debugger to the instance and run it line by line. For the first time, the value printed out is finished.

```
2020-12-01T10:10:34.863-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ResponsePlanStatus : StatusResponse(name=3379, state=finished, type=task
2020-12-01 10:10:34.863 WARN [,,,] 20 --- [l-2 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-2 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=3m3s928ms728µs779ns).
```

I'm still learning Kotlin but this is the most bizarre thing I have seen. How can a program print out a different value than what's in memory. The method on the last line just saves the data in the database table. It doesn't change the value whatsoever. What difference running the app with the debugger made? Could it be possible that response.body held the value from the previous request and then the current request came back after it was printed out in like some javascript type asynchronous fashion? Could that be the reason why it printed the correct output after I held up the thread with the debugger?

Comment: could the response body change mid execution? like if my puppet task changed from running to finished, could the value get updated through that rest template? I get a debug message: Connection can be kept alive indefinitely. Maybe if the api sends an updated value it gets updated in the code even after the resttemplate.exchange method ran

Comment: Yeah I'd assume that - when you're debugging you slow execution right down (sometimes stopping it) and other threads can run unimpeded. I'd look into that ``state`` property in the library code, if you can, and see if gets updated to ``finished`` (i.e. the value in the response gets changed, so it depends on when you look at it)